# Jordan measure and indicator function discontinuities

Tags: lebesgue-integral

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be Jordan measurable and bounded. Let $I\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be a closed and bounded interval such that $A \subset I$. We define the indicator function of $A$ as:
>
> $\chi_A:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x \,  $$\mapsto$$ \, \chi_A(x)= 
> \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{$x \in A$} \\[2ex]
> 0, & \text{$x \notin A$}
> \end{cases}$

The set of points where $\chi_A$ is not continuous is clearly contained in $Bd(A)$. My question is, can there be points of $Bd(A)$ where $\chi_A$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any boundary point $x$ there exist one sequence $\{y_n\}$ contained in $A$ and converging to $x$ and another sequence $\{z_n\}$ contained in $A^{c}$ and converging to $x$. Along the first sequence the limit is 1 and along the second sequence the limit is 0, so $\lim_{u \to x} \chi_A (u)$ does not exist. Hence the function is not continuous at any boundary point.